# aliginment and position issues when using display grid

Tags: html, css

I have 2 parent containers in my code below. The first one is just for reference for what I want my second container to look like. The difference between the two is the first one I used absolute positioning and flex display but the second one is grid display. What I'm stuck on is understanding how to center class `.item1` and position class `.item2` all the way to the right just how it's like on the first parent container i.e class `.topAdCon`. My specific questions are 1) how to center `.item1`
2) how to set `.item2's` position all the way to the right (right: 0%)
3) on the first parent container I just set `top: 0%` to align it all the way to the top because it has absolute positioning how can I set the positioning of the second parent container where ever I want currently I'm using margin-top for top positioning is that the way to go or what is the right way?
4) Lastly how do I set the height for the second container because `height` isn't responding as it does on the first container?

**Note:** I commented out things I tried in order to achieve these things but they aren't working.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.topAdCon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.topAdCon .adCon {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.topAdCon .adCon img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.topAdCon .sideInfo {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 17%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
}

.topAdCon .sideInfo p {
  font-size: 0.9vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*position: relative;
  top: 20%;*/
  margin-top: 20%;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 17%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18%;
  /*height not responding*/
  background-color: gold;
}

.item1 {
  /*align-self: center;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item2 {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  /*align-self: flex-end*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
}

.item2 p {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="topAdCon">
  <div class="adCon">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/356830/pexels-photo-356830.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" />
  </div>
  <div class="sideInfo">
    <p>this is test statement 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/356830/pexels-photo-356830.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" />
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <p>this is test statement 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.topAdCon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.topAdCon .adCon {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.topAdCon .adCon img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.topAdCon .sideInfo {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 17%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
}

.topAdCon .sideInfo p {
  font-size: 0.9vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 20%;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 40% 12% 18%;
  grid-template-areas: 'item item1 item2 item3';
  width: 100%;
  height: 18vh;
  background-color: gold;
}

.item1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
}

.item1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item3 {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: end;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
}

.item3 p {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="topAdCon">
  <div class="adCon">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/356830/pexels-photo-356830.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" />
  </div>
  <div class="sideInfo">
    <p>this is test statement 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/356830/pexels-photo-356830.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" />
  </div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3">
    <p>this is test statement 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```